# jquery image change doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code should work but I cant seem to find the problem why it doesnt work, I am testing it with google chrome

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.7.1_min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#unos').click(function() {
                $("#tre").attr('src', '/012/11/image2.jpg');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="tre" class="aligncenter" title="images" src="/012/11/image1.jpg" alt="" width="940" height="207" />
        <input id="unos" type="submit" name="change_src" value="change image" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in a $(document).ready?

Comment: @John no it is not as you can see

Comment: @TooCooL wrap it up and it should work

Comment: I did it but again it doesnt work!

Comment: It will also work if you put the script blocks at the end of your document -- you should really do that anyway to allow your page to load faster.

Comment: Comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/humKq/ No wrapper, http://jsfiddle.net/fT6r8/1/ With wrapper

Comment: As you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/thrss/ it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.7.1_min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#unos').click(function() {
                    $("#tre").attr('src', '/012/11/image2.jpg');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="tre" class="aligncenter" title="images" src="/012/11/image1.jpg" alt="" width="940" height="207" />
        <input id="unos" type="submit" name="change_src" value="change image" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or just put your JS before the end of your `<body>` tag

Comment: @Jamund Ferguson best is just before the closing body tag

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/7tsWM/